# SQL command not properly ended in dynamic sql query oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

I get an error

> SQL command not properly ended

Although the `p_sql` variable contains a valid SQL query that works without execute and loop.
Maybe this is due to the limitations of `execute immediate`

```
declare

p_sql clob;

begin

​for naprav in (select naprav_name from naprav)

​ ​ ​loop​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ for pokaz in (select * from pokaz)

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​loop

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​for group_level in (select * from group_level)

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​loop

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ p_sql := '

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ insert into from_cost_lab_with_love

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ with cte as (

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ select

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.i_id_pokaz || ' as i_id_pokaz,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_measure || ' as pokaz_measure,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_describe || ' as "Описание показателя",

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ naprav.naprav_name || ' as "Блок данных",

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.level_name || ' as level_name,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.tb_id || ' as tb_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.gosb_id || ' as gosb_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.org_id || ' as org_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_formula || ' over(' || group_level.partition_column || ') as fact_amt,' --показатель

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ||​ pokaz.pokaz_formula || ' over(' || group_level.partition_column || ') as fc_amt_1,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ row_number() over(' || group_level.partition_column || ' order by BE) as rnk

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ 0 as plan_amt,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',KVARTAL*3 - 3)),''01''), ''yyyymmdd'') as period_begin,​ --начало квартала

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',KVARTAL*3)),''01''), ''yyyymmdd'')) as period_end, --конец квартала

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',MESJATS)), ''01''), ''yyyymmdd'')) as rep_date, --дата измерений

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, ''dd.mm.yy'') as load_date,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ 0 as execution

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ from erp_trips

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ )

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ select *

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ from cte

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ where rnk=1;';

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ dbms_output.put_line(p_sql);

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​execute immediate p_sql;

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​end loop;

​ ​ ​ ​ ​end loop;

​ ​ ​end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from your SQL string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon (`;`) isn't part of the SQL syntax - it's a terminating character used by tools like SQL*Plus to signify the input is over and the SQL statement should be executed. When you execute an SQL statement directly (e.g., with `execute immediate`), you don't need it (read: it's wrong to have it). Remove it, and you should fine.